# Media Foundation : adding thirdparty decoder dll to topology

Tags: visual-studio-2008, multimedia, ms-media-foundation

I am new to Microsoft Media Foundation. I am running a sample playback code found in MSDN. Now, I want to add a MFT for a third party decoder to the topology. Is this possible ?

Thanks in advance,

Sri

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It is possible. Please look in your SDK installation directory. Go to `Microsoft SDKs -> v7.0 -> Samples -> Multimedia -> Mediafoundation -> Decoder` it contains a sample MPEG-1 decoder, which will give you an idea.

Answer (score 0):

According the decoder sample, we can realize ourself decoder mft,but there are one question about third_party MFT.
I add a amr codec MFT, and debug with topoedit(windows samplecode), it can play normally. but if I run windows media player, it donot play the file include amr codec. I think I need do something else  besides register  amr_mft.dll.